# MS Access Change Event Not Firing

Tags: vba, events, ms-access

I am running the Change Event below to populate standard contact information.  This has worked well when I select a name from the drop down menu.  However, often times I just start typing the Account to find the correct one since it can be faster than scrolling through the Account list. However, when I tab or click to the next field its not recognizing the change and doesn't fire.  What am I missing?

```
Private Sub cboAccountID_Change()
' Adds Account info to invoice
    Invoice_To = DLookup("Invoice_To", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    Invoice_Email = DLookup("Invoice_Email", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    Service_Type = DLookup("Service_Type", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    Client_Rate = DLookup("Client_Rate", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    Address = DLookup("Address", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    Unit_Suite = DLookup("Unit_Suite", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    City = DLookup("City", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    State = DLookup("State", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
    Zip = DLookup("Zip", "tblClientLists", "AccountID =" & Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `After Update` event instead of `On Change`?

Comment: @GordThompson I used the After Update and it worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think that because you are typing you are not actually changing/submitting anything. so the code has to be changed slightly from

`Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID`

to

`Forms![frmInvoices]!AccountID.Text`

(i'm not sure how the lookups will respond as you type.)

Comment: Actually, when typing into a Combo Box its `On Change` event fires for every character you type.

Comment: ok, that's good, as it should. just wasn't sure how the lookups will react with incomplete data. should be ok, just won't return anything until something useful is typed, i guess.